# Comparing two equivalent definite integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

Reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777449/problems-regarding-the-ratio-of-two-definite-integrals) on Math.SE, I tried the following Mathematica instructions

```
In[1]:= i1 = Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 + t^4], {t, 0, 1}];
        i2 = Integrate[Sec[u]^2/Sqrt[1 + Tan[u]^4], {u, 0, \[Pi]/4}];
        FullSimplify[i1 == i2]
        FullSimplify[i1 == i2] // N
Out[3]= Sqrt[\[Pi]] EllipticK[1/2] == 4 Gamma[5/4]^2
Out[4]= True
```

so, given that the two integrals are the same, apart from a change of variable, I ask: why Mathematica does not know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`FunctionExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html)

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

i1 = Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 + t^4], {t, 0, 1}]

(* (2 Gamma[5/4]^2)/Sqrt[π] *)

i2 = Integrate[Sec[u]^2/Sqrt[1 + Tan[u]^4], {u, 0, π/4}]

(* 1/2 EllipticK[1/2] *)

i1 == i2 // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: I didn't know about `FunctionExpand`. Help page says: `FunctionExpand` is automatically called by `FullSimplify`, so why it is needed?

Comment: Presumably, `FullSimplify`'s algorithms did not recognize this as a situation for which `FunctionExpand` was appropriate or, if it took that path, it concluded that it was getting worse rather than better before getting to the desired result. In any event, explicitly specifying `FunctionExpand` helped it find the right path. In general, you cannot assume that `FullSimplify` tried all possible approaches and when you are not getting the result that you expect, you should try and help it. The `See Also` section of documentation (for `FullSimplify` in this case) can provide useful hints.